# Sorting screen coordinates

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a Vector `textCommands` which holds structs called `TextCommand` containing a `RECT` and a string; and a `RECT` has value `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` all in screen coordinates. I'm wondering how I would sort this vector so that I can then call `std::unique` and remove the duplicate entries. Duplicate entry being an entry that has the same string, and an identical `RECT` where all the values are the same.

```
//Location in screen coordinates(pixels)
struct RECT
{
    int top;
    int left;
    int bottom;
    int right;
};

//text at location RECT
struct TextCommand
{
    std::string text;
    RECT pos;
};

std::vector<TextCommand> textCommands;
```

Comment: Sort you say? Use `std::sort`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious you beat me to it. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Which parameter would I sort by?

Comment: All. Write a comparator that satisfies strict weak ordering. Also, have you thought of using `std::set`?

Comment: @LogicStuff I thought of using set, but I thought that you needed a unique key for every entry, and the text couldn't be the key because the same text could be printed multiple times on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a custom comparator (functor, lambda, or overloaded `operator <`) satisfying strict weak ordering that you can feed into `std::sort` or `std::set`. The simplest one would be:

```
#include <tuple>

struct TextCommandCompare
{
    bool operator()(TextCommand const& a, TextCommand const& b) const
    {
        return std::tie(a.text, a.pos.top, a.pos.left, a.pos.bottom, a.pos.right) <
            std::tie(b.text, b.pos.top, b.pos.left, b.pos.bottom, b.pos.right);
    }
};
```

`std::tie` creates a `std::tuple` that implements the lexicographic comparison for you.